# Full form of ttwu in the scheduling code of the linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I know this is kind of silly, but I tried to find out online, but couldnt.

What is the full-form of **ttwu** in the scheduler code of the linux kernel. It can be seen as a number of function prefixes, namely,

```
ttwu_do_wakeup
ttwu_do_activate
ttwu_queue_remote
ttwu_activate
.. and many more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume it stands for `try_to_wake_up`. See for example the comment in `kernel/sched/sched.h`:

```
 981     /* try_to_wake_up() stats */
 982     unsigned int        ttwu_count;
 983     unsigned int        ttwu_local;
```

Comment: Yep. after reading your (so very correct) assumption, I went back to the code and looked for it, and there it was..

`try_to_wake_up - wake up a thread` in the description comment of the function `try_to_wake_up()`. I am guessing this was an older function, and the in the newer ones they just abbreviated it..

Answer (score 1):

yes in true *nix philosophy why waste time on extra characters (e.g. you want to know the current working directory?  Use `pwd` for "print working directory")  `TTWU` is indeed "Try To Wake Up" and implemented in the Linux scheduler code, eventually calling `activate_task`, which actually DOES NOT DO ANYTHING but put the task on the run queue of one of the CPUs.  At some point in the future the `_schedule` function will make it activate (via `switch_context`.)  Pretty cool stuff if you ask me.